# Bootstrap - Change or appear to change row layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page with this layout:

[image]

On smaller screens (iPad), I want the layout to **look** like this. I emphasize the "look" because all I really need is to have Div 3 sit next to Div 1 while Div 2 appears to take up the full row:
[image]

I've read about using rows where the sum of columns is more than 12 - is that something that I can apply here? Any help would be great!

Comment: What's the desired order on an iPhone?

Comment: Div 1: full width, Div 2: full width, Div 3: hidden

Comment: I'd definitely go for all three children of the same parent `.row`. What version of Bootstrap are you using? v3, v4? What I'd suggest here is flexbox. In v4 it's built in, in v3, it needs a bit of CSS added. If you don't want flexbox, let me know, so I don't waste time answering. :)

Comment: I'm using Version 3

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the current structure without hacking the DOM with jQuery, or showing/hiding with CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired layout is achievable in these conditions:

- You place all your `.col-*`s as direct children of the same parent `.row`
- The `.col-*` containing `div 3` is the second child, has `float:right` and class of `xs-hidden`
- last column is `col-md-9 col-sm-12`

Proof of concept:

```css
.custom-layout>div:nth-child(2) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row custom-layout">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="red-border">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
      <div>
         <h2> Column 3 </h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
      <div>
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```